# Animate.css conflict with chrome mobile device

Tags: css, google-chrome, animate.css

I used animate.css with bootstrap 3. When i scroll chrome in mobile device mode my navbar is hide and sheek. I confirm the animate.css is the main reasone for this. But i want to use animate.css. Its only happened with chrome. What should i do. Advance Thanks.

Comment: Would you provide why anmate.css is the reason for you problem?

Comment: I dont know but when i'm disable the animate.css there is no problem. So i think that.

Thanks.